# vsftpd fails pam authentication

Tags: security, ftp, authentication, pam

Moving a tried-and-true vsftpd configuration onto a new server with Fedora 16, I ran into a problem.  All seems to go as it should, but user authentication fails.  I cannot find any entry in any log that indicates what happened.

Here is the full config file:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
idle_session_timeout=0
data_connection_timeout=0
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
connect_from_port_20=YES
listen=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen_ipv6=NO

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

FTP challenges me for a username and password, I provide them, Login Incorrect.  I have verified, this user is able to login from ssh.  Something is screwed up with `pam_service`.

Anonymous (if changed to allowed) seems to work well.

SELinux is disabled.

Ftpsecure appears to be configured fine... I am at a complete loss!

Here are the log files I examined with no success:

```
/var/log/messages
/var/log/xferlog      #empty
/var/log/vsftpd.log   #empty
/var/log/secure
```

Found something in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`:

`type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1335632253.332:18486): user pid=19528 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="kate" exe="/usr/sbin/vsftpd" hostname=ip68-5-219-23.oc.oc.cox.net addr=68.5.219.23 terminal=ftp res=failed'`

Perhaps I should look at `/var/log/wtf-is-wrong.help`  :-)

Further info:

/etc/pam.d/vsftpd looks like this:

```
#%PAM-1.0
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth       required     pam_shells.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    include      password-auth
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    include      password-auth
```

Comment: What's the PAM configuration (`/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`, I think)?

Comment: Try `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg`.

Comment: pam config:session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth       required     pam_shells.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    include      password-auth
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    include      password-auth

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Whew.  I solved the problem.  It amounts to a config but within /etc/pam.d/vsftpd

Because ssh sessions succeeded while ftp sessions failed, I went to

/etc/pam.d/vsftpd, removed everything that was there and instead placed the contents of ./sshd to match the rules precisely.  All worked!

By method of elimination, I found that the offending line was:

```
    auth       required     pam_shells.so
```

Removing it allows me to proceed.

Tuns out, "pam_shells is a PAM module that only allows access to the system if the users shell is listed in /etc/shells."  I looked there and sure enough, no bash, no nothing.  This is a bug in vsftpd configuration in my opinion as nowhere in the documentation does it have you editing /etc/shells.  Thus default installation and instructions do not work as stated.

I'll go find where I can submit the bug now.

Comment: /etc/shells is typically supposed to contain a list of acceptable shells. This is used by quite a few different subsystems and is expected to be correct. This file isn't created or maintained by vsftpd, but rather by your distro's core setup. So this isn't a vsftpd bug, it's a bug with your computer's setup.

Comment: God thanks ! I should've seen that user unable to log in matched those with /sbin/nologin as user shell...

Comment: Thank you so much! Your comment about `/etc/shells` helped me to find the reason for this strange behaviour change. The FTP-User was created with `Shell: /sbin/nologin` and `/sbin/nologin` turned out to be removed from `/etc/shells`. So I added the lines `/sbin/nologin` and `/usr/sbin/nologin` which made `auth       required     pam_shells.so` work too.

Answer (score 4):

I am using ubuntu and had same issue

Solution:

```
add-shell /sbin/nologin
sudo usermod -s /sbin/nologin ftpme
sudo vi /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
```

Then comment and add lines as following

```
#%PAM-1.0
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers  onerr=succeed
auth       required     pam_shells.so
#auth       include      password-auth
#account    include      password-auth
#session    required     pam_loginuid.so
#session    include      password-auth
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case I opted for comment the auth line in the **/etc/pam.d/vsftpd** config file

```
#%PAM-1.0
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
auth       required     pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/f$
#auth       required    pam_shells.so
auth       include  password-auth
account    include  password-auth
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    include  password-auth
```

Here you are the reason.
If you add **/sbin/nologin** as a shell system, you probably could open an unwanted backdoor in your system.
Instead, changing this file surely you only affects **vsftpd**.

I don't know if another process like **sshd** looks for system shells, but I think changing pam.d file is better solution than others.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your own answer, the user shell should be listed in `/etc/shells`. You could set `/sbin/nologin` as user shell to forbid ssh and allow ftp without changing pam configuration:

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin restricted_ftp_user
```

Answer (score 0):

If vsftpd fails with an error of

> vsftpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2

Then another possibility is to check if
`pasv_addr_resolve=YES` is set in the `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file. This causes the hostname of the FTP server to be resolved via DNS.  If DNS won't resolve, like if you can't `ping yourhostname.example.com`, then you'll need to fix that DNS resolution problem or set `pasv_addr_resolve=NO` in the `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` and it should at least let vsftpd start without the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same strange behaviour where a FTP-User configured with

```
# finger <user>
Login: <user>                   Name: 
Directory: /home/user-dir           Shell: /sbin/nologin
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.
```

on one System is able to log in and on the other not.

In extention to the Answer of @KateYoak it turned out that the `/etc/shells` File was different and did not include the `/sbin/nologin` shell.
which made the PAM Authentication in `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`

```
auth       required     pam_shells.so
```

fail

By just adding to the `/etc/shells` File the missing lines

```
/sbin/nologin
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

the check in `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` worked.

So a working `/etc/shells` File should have:

```
# cat /etc/shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/nologin
/bin/tcsh
/bin/csh
```

---

In more recent Versions (Centos8) the `/etc/shells` only contains:

```
# cat /etc/shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
```

and User Accounts in those Systems are created with the `/usr/bin/false` Shell:

```
# cat /etc/passwd|grep -i ftp_user01
ftp_user01:x:1004:1004:FTP Account for user01:/home/user01:/usr/bin/false
```

Even though this configuration will not give automatically FTP Login what way.

```
$ ftp ftp-server02.domain.com
Connected to ftp-server02.domain.com (ip.add.re.ss).
220 FTP Service of Server ftp-server02
Name (ftp-server02.domain.com:local_user02): ftp_user01
331 Password required for ftp_user01
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

It is **always required** to insert `/usr/bin/false` into `/etc/shells`
So the **Minimum Configuration** to get the FTP working should be:

```
# cat /etc/shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/false
```

---

Site Note about the thought from @Greeso :

The `man` pages on `/sbin/nologin` explain:
[man page `nologin`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nologin.8.html):

> **nologin** displays a message that an account is not available and exits non-zero.  It is intended as a replacement shell field to deny
> login access to an account.
> **nologin** is a per-account way to disable login (usually used for
> system accounts like http or ftp).

So actually running the `/usr/sbin/nologin` Command it displays:

```
$ /usr/sbin/nologin ; echo "res: '$?'"
This account is currently not available.
res: '1'
```

So **bots** that try a bruteforce attack on the system and get this message can use it to conclude that the Account exists in the System and that the Login is for a FTP or HTTP Service.
So you can understand the change as a strategy to harden the System Security.

Comment: Although this works, I am wondering if this causes a security problem! I am not sure, but there might be a good reason that the 'nologin; shells were not included in the shells

Comment: @gree This was a good point about why this change was done. The `nologin` Command does still exist on all Linux Systems because it is part of the Kernel. But from the man pages I understand that it was considered to give to much information out. See my Edit for details.

Answer (score -2):

Back up the config file before making a change;

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.back
```

and then edit vsftpd.conf (with vi or nano)

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then make the following change

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

Save your change and restart the ftp server (if you use nano hit CTRL+O & enter to save then CTRL+X to exit)

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```