# VSFTP local user works, but PAM users Permission Denied

Tags: arch-linux, pam, vsftpd

I am attempting to configure `vsftp` to use PAM to authenticate virtual users on my Arch server. It seems so straight forward, I must be missing something simple.

#### Configuration

- local user `virtualftp` in group `virtualftp`
- folders `/srv/ftp` and `/srv/ftp/test1` owned by `virtualftp:virtualftp`
- PAM user `test1` with password `test1p` in `/etc/vsftpd_login.db`

/etc/pam.d/vsftpd

```
auth required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd_login crypt=hash
account required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd_login crypt=hash
session required pam_loginuid.so
```

/etc/vsftp.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to MCID's FTP server.
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
listen=YES
# nopriv_user=virtualftp

# SSL Configuration
# ssl_enable=YES
# allow_anon_ssl=NO
# force_local_data_ssl=NO
# force_local_logins_ssl=YES
# ssl_tlsv1=YES
# ssl_sslv2=YES
# ssl_sslv3=YES
# rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
# rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem

# Passive Port Range
pasv_min_port=49152
pasv_max_port=65534

# Added settings for PAM virtualftp logins
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=virtualftp
virtual_use_local_privs=YES

# Private folders for virtual users
local_root=/srv/ftp/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
```

Currently I can login with `sftp://theherk@sftp.example.com` (my local user) just fine. However, if I attempt to login with `test1`, I get "permission denied". What am I missing or confused about?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37539/vsftpd-fails-pam-authentication

Answer (score 1):

vsftpd (very secure FTP daemon) is an FTP daemon, and has nothing to do with sftp (SSH File Transfer Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for virtual users to enable write access:

```
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
```