# Solaris 5.10 shell replacement for Centos 7 migration

Tags: shell, centos, useradd, usermod

I have an old Solaris 5.10 server. I'm migrating the tomcat products to Centos 7. There are two accounts on the Solaris server that I need to migrate. The shells for both of those accounts are identified as "/usr/local/bin/ftponly". This looks like a simple SH script, but I can't tell if it came with the server or if a previous admin (or vendor tech) wrote it. This script and "/bin/sh" are the only items in "/etc/shells".

On the new Centos 7 server, I chose "/usr/sbin/nologin" as the two users's shells. "/usr/local/bin/ftponly" on the old server is a human readable script, but "/usr/sbin/nologin" appears to be a binary file. FTP transactions on the new server with the two user accounts in question are working, and SSH is denied.

Am I good to go or are there larger considerations with the available shells? My bread and butter Linux OS is Ubuntu, so some of the security built-ins of Centos have me scratching my head at times.

Comment: What does ftponly do, if anything?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, echoes a message to the console and exits.

Comment: In which case I believe you're good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that varies by operating system.  It varies by FTP server software.

What counts as a *real person* user account in Unix is non-trivial to determine programmatically.  Impersonal user accounts can both have non-empty shell fields in the system account database that point to real executables (e.g. `uucico`) and valid, existing, home directories (e.g. `/var/spool/news`).

The convention employed by at least two non-anonymous FTP servers is that a user account is a real person for FTP purposes, and can thus perform FTP login, if the shell field in its record in the system accounts database is non-empty and has a value that can be found in the system "user shells" table (`/etc/shells` for one of those two, per the `getusershell()` library function in the case of the other).

Clearly, as one can tell from the name alone, the `/usr/local/bin/ftponly` shell is taking advantage of this in order to have user accounts that execute what is probably a very simple emit-a-message-and-log-off program when the user attempts a *terminal* log-on, but that work for *FTP* log-on.

`nologin` will do the same job if it is in the user shells table.  But this is specific to the FTP server software that you happen to be using.  Another FTP server software *on the same operating system* will have quite different rules.

[Bruce Guenter's twoftpd](http://untroubled.org/twoftpd/), for example, tests the value of the shell field against two configuration settings.  If it matches one, the client gets read-only FTP service with the `twoftpd-anon` program.  If it matches the other, the client gets file-upload-only FTP service with the `twoftpd-drop` program.

Even the software that you may be using might have complex configuration options that affect this.  In vsftpd, for example, the `check_shell` option, the `local_enable` option, the `pam_service_name` option, and the PAM configuration for that service (including the presence and configuration of the `pam_shells` module) are all involved.

## Further reading

- [What's the difference between /sbin/nologin and /bin/false](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/)
- [vsftpd fails pam authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37539/)